# Selenium, scraping Youtube creators with less then 500 subscribers (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, youtube

Below is my code  for simple search in Youtube  that user inputed, but I want to be getting users with only  **less then 500 subscribers**  and export them in *Excel file*, is there anyone who can give me an idea how to do that?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
path = "https://youtube.com"
driver.get(path)
#xpath for search box
x_path_for_box = "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[4]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"
searching_point_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_box)
#user manual input
search_word = input("Enter the search keyword: ")
searching_point_box.send_keys(search_word)
#xpath for search button
x_path_search_button= "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[4]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/button"
searchButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_search_button)
searchButton.click()
```

Comment: Can you share the error trace?

Comment: As far as I know you can't filter on subscribers count both on YouTube UI and [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint.

Comment: Keep in mind that some Youtube users has their subscriber count hidden. Also, with this code you shared, do you have any errors or something?

Comment: Thanks for answering, there is no error, it does everything perfectly up till that point, but I'm not sure how to get  number of subscribers, i want for example to input lets say "Aviation" it gets on that topic and i only want YouTubers with count less then 500. I'm not sure how to do that.